# How to fixe 'FileNotFoundError' ... parsers.py in parser_f?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm importing a dataset with python but it does not works, pandas, numpy and seaborn imported well.

I tried with the full path and the short one (the dataset and the python files are in the same folder...).

My code :

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
```

we can see that it s maybe an encoding problem but I puted enconding = 'utf_8', nothing append..
The last error message is :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 17: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 dataset = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv", encoding='utf_8')

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, doublequote, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    676                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    677 
--> 678         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    679 
    680     parser_f.__name__ = name

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    444 
    445     try:
--> 446         data = parser.read(nrows)
    447     finally:
    448         parser.close()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1034                 raise ValueError('skipfooter not supported for iteration')
   1035 
-> 1036         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1037 
   1038         # May alter columns / col_dict

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1846     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1847         try:
-> 1848             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1849         except StopIteration:
   1850             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 17: invalid start byte
```

Thank you all in advance !

Comment: "Hope we gonna solve this problem" love this line, however, is this the full traceback?

Comment: That file does not exist in the current directory.  Easy peasy.

Comment: ahah some times it's funny to exagerate ..
FileNotFoundError: File b'dataset.csv' does not exist

Comment: @AlexandreNtf exactly, please include the full path of the file when reading. :)

Comment: @JohnGordon but it is in the same directory. I just tried and same result

Comment: How are you running this program?  If you're using an IDE or something similar, perhaps the current directory isn't what you think it is.  Add this to your program and show us the output: `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: @JohnGordon result : /Users/alexandrenataf/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/.Trash/L'amour 18.49.53

Comment: ooh I know, at the beggining I delete one file but after I downloaded it again in my desktop.. SUrely I had to clean the trash no?

Comment: So finally I ve tried to print(os.getcwvd()) and you can see the ErrorMessage  below

Comment: Don't post code/exception as an answer. It is part of the question. @AlexandreNtf

Comment: @Vishnudev ok :). So I add the message on the answer, there is a new one .. btw i'm using vscode